# Laravel one page crud Select all from table2 where id = table1.id

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a laravel application where i have 2 tables:

folder: id, name

subfolder: id, name, folder_id

'folder_id' is linked to the id of the folder table.

Now i have a page with all the folder's. and a click to see all the subfolders that have the same 'folder_id' as the 'id' of the folder column.

folder.index:

```
 @foreach($folders as $folder)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$folder->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$folder->name}} </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.subfolder.index',$folder->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View {{$folder->name}}</a>
            </td>
```

subfolder.index:

```
 @foreach($subfolders as $subfolder)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$subfolder->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$subfolder->name}} </td>
            <td>{{$subfolder->folder->name}} </td>

            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('admin.subfolder.edit',$subfolder->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('admin.subfolder.destroy', $subfolder->id)}}" method="post">
                  @csrf
                  @method('DELETE')
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

if i click on the folder.index button i go to the subfolder page with an number in the url. the ID, but for some reason my $specificfolders query (SQL version: SELECT * FROM `subfolder` INNER JOIN folder on subfolder.folder_id = folder.id WHERE folder.id = (the id i give);) in the controller always return empty.
i made an if statement because i have a one page crud page.

subfolder controller (removed unnecessary code) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;


class SubfolderController extends Controller
{
  
    public function index(Request $folder_id)
    {  $specificfolders = DB::table('subfolder')->select('*')->join('folder', 'subfolder.folder_id', '=', 'folder.id')->where('folder.id', $folder_id)->get();

       if($specificfolders->isEmpty())
       {
        $subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->get();
        $folders = Folder::all();
      
        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }
       else {
        $subfolders = Subfolder::where('folder_id', $folder_id)->with('folder')->get();
        $folders = Folder::all();
        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index(Request $folder_id)
```

$folder_id here is a Request and not a String containing the actual ID you are passing in the request.

So you need to retrieve the id from the request, you can do something like this.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {  $specificfolders = DB::table('subfolder')->select('*')->join('folder', 'subfolder.folder_id', '=', 'folder.id')->where('folder.id', $request->get('id'))->get();

       if($specificfolders->isEmpty())
       {
        $subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->get();
        $folders = Folder::all();
      
        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }
       else {
        $subfolders = Subfolder::where('folder_id', $folder_id)->with('folder')->get();
        $folders = Folder::all();
        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }
    }
```

Assuming `folder_id` is the name of the variable you are passing in you reqeust.

You can find out more about retrieving inputs from request in the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: <a href="{{ route('admin.subfolder.index',$folder->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary">View {{$folder->name}}</a> 
if i am correct i am passing 'id' here. or do i need to add something because it doest not work

Comment: can you try using `$request->get('id')`

Comment: i guess we are one step further. now i get this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty()
on this line:   if($specificfolders->isEmpty())

Comment: mhh once `->get()` is called you should have a collection and not a `Builder` so it looks really strange to me, double check what the `->get()` is returning

Comment: i fixed that error and now i get this error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$id

new code:  $specificfolders = DB::table('subfolder')->select('*')->join('folder', 'subfolder.folder_id', '=', 'folder.id')->where('folder.id', $request->get('id'));
       if($specificfolders)
       {
        $subfolders = DB::table('subfolder')->select('*')->join('folder', 'subfolder.folder_id', '=', 'folder.id')->where('folder.id', $request->get('id'));
        $folders = Folder::all();
        return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }

Comment: if you don't use `->get()` you aren't actually running ht query but you are jut passing a query builder to your view and not actual results

Answer (score 0):

//In folder model

```
public function subfolder()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subfolder::class,'id','folder_id');
}
```

// In controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
       $specificfolders = Folder::With('subfolder')->find($request->id);


       if(empty($specificfolders)){
            $subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->get();
            $folders = Folder::all();
      
            return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }
       else {
            $subfolders = Subfolder::with('folder')->where('folder_id', $request->id)->get();
            $folders = Folder::all();
            return view('admin.subfolder.index', compact('subfolders', 'folders'));
       }


}
```

Comment: Please give us more information about this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).